# How to record with an external microphone on my Lenovo G50-70 laptop

Tags: audio, microphone, lenovo-laptop

How can I record with an external microphone on my Lenovo G50-70 laptop? Normally most laptops have two jack in input, one for headset/ear piece and the other for a mic. This enables you connect a recording jack to your laptop and your mixer to record. However, I do not have this microphone-in port. I do not know if there are alternative means for recording without that.

Answer (score 3):

You have four options:

1. Use the built-in audio
2. Use a combo jack (on the Lenovo website, it says that it is a combo jack, so use something like what is pictured below)

   [image: inline mic]
3. Use an adapter like this: [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004SP0WAQ)

   [image]
4. Use a USB microphone

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a USB sound card with both outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get a splitter mentioned in the other answer to work (tried two).

I tried a USB mic and it works perfectly so there is that as an option.